# istio - using vs service and gw instead loadbalancer not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, istio

I’ve the following application which Im able to run in K8S successfully which using service with type load balancer, very simple app with two routes

1. `/` - you should see 'hello application`
2. `/api/books` should provide list of book in json format

This is the `service`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: go-ms
  labels:
    app: go-ms
    tier: service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: go-ms
```

This is the **deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-ms
  labels:
    app: go-ms

spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: go-ms
        tier: service

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: go-ms
          image: rayndockder/http:0.0.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "8080"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "125m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
```

after applied the both yamls and when calling the URL:

`http://b0751-1302075110.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/books`

**I was able to see the data in the browser as expected and also for the root app using just the external ip**

Now I want to use `istio`, so I follow the guide and install it successfully via `helm`
using https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/ and verify that all the 53 crd are there and also `istio-system` 
 components (such as `istio-ingressgateway` 
`istio-pilot` etc all 8 deployments are in up and running)

I’ve change the service above from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort`

and create the following `istio` config according to the istio docs

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 8080
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - http-gateway
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/"
      - uri:
          exact: "/api/books"
    route:
      - destination:
          port:
            number: 8080
          host: go-ms
```

in addition I’ve added the following

`kubectl label namespace books istio-injection=enabled` where the application is deployed,

Now to get the external Ip i've used command

`kubectl get svc -n istio-system -l istio=ingressgateway`

and get this in the `external-ip`

`b0751-1302075110.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`
when trying to access to the URL

`http://b0751-1302075110.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/books`

I got error:

This site can’t be reached

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

if I run the docker `rayndockder/http:0.0.2` via
`docker run -it -p 8080:8080 httpv2`

I path's works correctly!

Any idea/hint What could be the issue ?

Is there a way to **trace** the `istio` configs to see whether if something is missing or we have some collusion with port or network policy maybe ?

btw, the deployment and service can run on each cluster for testing of someone could help...

if I **change** all to port to `80` (in all yaml files and the application and the docker ) I was able to get the data for the root path, but not for "api/books"

Comment: Can you paste the output of the command,
`kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].port}'` ?

Comment: @Malathi - the output of this command is `80`

Comment: Can you please change the port to 80 from 8080 in the gateway yaml and try?

Comment: @Malathi - it already configured like this, I try to change to `80` or `8080` and still the same issue, should I change the port in all the files to `80` ?

Comment: @Malathi - Do you have `istio` installed ? did you try to run this app ?

Comment: yeah I tried with minikube. Please refer to my answer for detailed explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194115/discussion-between-malathi-and-jhon-d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tired your config with the modification of gateway port to 80 from 8080 in my local minikube setup of kubernetes and istio. This is the command I used:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: go-ms
  labels:
    app: go-ms
    tier: service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: go-ms
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-ms
  labels:
    app: go-ms

spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: go-ms
        tier: service

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: go-ms
          image: rayndockder/http:0.0.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "8080"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "125m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: go-ms-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
     - "*"
  gateways:
    - http-gateway
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /
      - uri:
          exact: /api/books
    route:
      - destination:
          port:
            number: 8080
          host: go-ms
EOF
```

The reason that I changed the gateway port to 80 is that, the istio ingress gateway by default opens up a few ports such as 80, 443 and few others. In my case, as minikube doesn't have an external load balancer, I used node ports which is 31380 in my case.

I was able to access the app with url of http://$(minikube ip):31380.

There is no point in changing the port of services, deployments since these are application specific.

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994034/istio-what-for-all-these-ports-are-opened-on-loadbalancer) question specifies the ports opened by istio ingress gateway.

Comment: Thanks, I need to leave the office now, i'll check it ASAP and let you know tomorrow

Comment: HI, Does it works for you? you are able to see the application response in the browser ? i've tried to use the yaml which you have provided `as-is` and Im not able to get the application data from the browser ...

Comment: when accessing the `load balancer` like: `http://b0751-1302075110.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` im getting http response `503`

Comment: I am also facing same issue. My application is using 443 with cluster ip. So when I am hitting istio loadbalancer, it suicks. But if I user loadbalancer and do not use istio then working fine. Please guide.